# Mean Value of a six faced die that have 5 3's and 1 6,after 6000 rolls

Tags: dice, expected-value

This question is asked today in an exam and perplexed me.I can't quite fit the 6000 rolls in the solution.I want to know how the roll number effects the outcome of mean value(expected value) of this one particular die.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you saying that, out of $6000$ throws, you only get five $3's$ and one $6$?  Is this meant to be a fair die?

Comment: Or are you saying that, of the six faces, one of them shows $6$ and the other five all show $3$?

Comment: I think the OP probably means the expected value of the sum of $6,000$ rolls of a balanced die with five $3$s and one $6$ on the faces.

Comment: To clarify:  I think you mean that it IS a fair die, in the sense that each face is equally likely to come up, but it isn't standard....one face shows a $6$ and the other five show $3$. Yes?  Assuming so, then note that out of six thousand rolls you expect to see the $6$ one thousand times.

Comment: Yes it is a fair die,"one face shows a 6 and the other five show 3. Yes?",exactly but want i want is the expected value or mean value of 6000 rolls with this particular die.Not the expected value of sum by the way.

Comment: @saulspatz not the "expected value of sum" just the "expected value" or "mean value".

Comment: Do you mean the expected value of the average of $6,000$ rolls then?   It's the same as the average value of one roll.

Comment: Well, unless we are there and recorded the rolls we can't know the actual mean value.  If you rolled a $6$, $1256$ times the mean value will be $3.628$ But if you rolled a $6$, $810$ times the mean value will be $3.405$.  The *expected* value of a roll (and the expected mean value of 6000 rolls) is $\frac {5*3 + 6}6 = 3.5$.  This it true no matter how many rolls.  Are you sure you understand exaction what the question is asking.  (I certainly do not.)

Comment: @saulspatz is "average value of one roll" an acceptable/meaningful term?  (I'm asking sincerely; not rhetorically).

Comment: @saulspatz i thought the same thing.Then the fact that there is given roll number is the trick part?

Comment: @fleablood i'm sure of it,it was a short question,i read it many times and your answer is quite what i want to know.

Comment: I imagine the question is what is the expected total.  ANd the expected total is $6*1000 + 3*5000$ or $3.5*6000$ and is $21000$.  But I'm only guessing what your question might mean.  The answer to the question you wrote: "What is the mean Value of a six faced die that have 5 3's and 1 6,after 6000 rolls" is "a piece of plastic with markings on it that is a bit worn out".  The *die* is a physical object.  It doesn't have a mean value any more than an elephant does.  So we need to know exactly what the question actually was.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I think so.  "Average value" and "expected value" are synonyms as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @fleablood In question it wasn't the sum,just the expected value of 6000 rolls of this particular die,like the mean value of a regular die is 3.5,but there is also given a roll number as you can see.

Comment: This isn't a question of math but interpretation.  I personally would read "the expected value of 6000 rolls" to mean the expected for value of the total of 6000 rolls.  But interpretation is not math.  The average/expected value of the die is 3.5 and the expected total of k rolls is $3.5k$ and ... there's not much more to say.

Comment: @fleablood I know,believe me,it was weird to me and again i remember the question exactly,i expected it to be sum like you do when i read it right there and then,maybe it was a flawed question or tricky one.